# XAMPP/AJAX/PHP Issue with saving

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, xampp

I'm very new to programming and have been trying to make a website application to learn some web development, using XAMPP on Windows as the local web server.  I've gotten to the point where I'm trying to incorporate some AJAX by loading some info from the database asynchronously.  But any time I make a change to the PHP file that is being called by myFunction() below and save it, the updates don't show up when I refresh the page.  I have to close and reopen the browser in order for the changes I've made to appear.  The only thing I can think of is that when the browser gets closed the session gets destroyed, but I can't figure out why an update to the PHP file shouldn't show up when I refresh the page.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the file that is shown in the browser:

```
<?php
    include 'core/init.php';
    include 'includes/overall/header.php';
    protect_page();
?>
<body>
    <div id="ticker">
    <?php
        include 'includes/teams.php';
    ?>
    </div>

    <div id="teaminfo"></div>

    <h2>Welcome to your homepage, <?php echo $user_data['first_name']; ?></h2>

    <a href="createleague.php">Create a League</a><br><br>

    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br><br>

    <script>
    function myFunction(team_id) 
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("teaminfo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'teaminfo.php?x=' + team_id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

and the php page:

```
<?php
include 'core/database/connect.php';
$team_id = $_GET['x'];

$sql = "SELECT name, wins, losses FROM hockey_team WHERE id = '$team_id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<h1 id='team_name'>" . $row['name'] . "</h1>";
    echo "<p id='wins'>" . $row['wins'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p id='losses'>" . $row['losses'] . "</p>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you need to call the javascript function "myFunction" somehow from your script/html page to get the refresh working. Like using a button somewhere in your page.

I'm not seeing any call to the function then. You have to understand the js "myFunction" is not called just by reloading the page. It is just defined there.

The same purpose of ajax is to avoid this page reloading routine.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that. I create divs dynamically in teams.php that call myFunction() when they are clicked.  So when those divs are created they are <div onclick='myFunction(this.id)'>some stuff</div>. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a good idea, like someone else responded here, to declare the function after all the page or dom has loaded. The thing is the sample they gave you above uses the library JQuery and you are using the plain original ajax here. So I recommend you use something like window.onload = myFunction(){...}; to declare your function. Also, another tip, pass null inside xmlhttp.send(null);

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm still having a problem with saving.  I can load the page and everything will work, then go into the PHP and simply delete a semicolon somewhere, save the page (which in theory should now return an error), refresh the page, and everything will continue to work. I can even kill the session by logging out, log back in and everything will work. But if I close the browser, open it back up and log in, it will show an error.  I can't figure out if it's a cache problem or a session problem or what. Any ideas? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your function inside
$(document).ready(function() {
   myFunction(team_id){
     ...
   }
});

Because your div's are created dynamically, so may be wait for the DOM to load fully.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research I believe I've answered my own question. I'm new here so I'm not sure if I'm supposed to post it, but I figure it could help someone in the future. The problem was with Internet Explorer. It caches AJAX requests, so when I changed something on the server, then ran the request again, it wasn't going back to the server, but grabbing what happened last time. I've simply switched to using Firefox for developing, but would have to make sure IE doesn't cache the request if this was a live website.